# Find maximum in a group, subset by a subset from a different dataframe, to select other value's

Tags: r

I have two data.frames df1 with raw data. df2 has information on where to look in df1.
df1 has groups, defined by "id". In those groups, a subset is defined by df2$value_a1 and df2$value_a2, which represent the range of rows to look in the group. In that subsetgroup I want to find the maximum value_a, to select value_b.

code for df1 and df2

```
df1 <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), "value_a" = c(0, 10, 21, 30, 43, 53, 69, 81, 93, 5, 16, 27, 33, 45, 61, 75, 90, 2, 11, 16, 24, 31, 40, 47, 60, 75, 88), "value_b" = c(100, 101, 100, 95, 90, 104, 88, 84, 75, 110, 105, 106, 104, 95, 109, 96, 89, 104, 104, 104, 103, 106, 103, 101, 99, 98, 97), "value_c" = c(0, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0), "value_d" = c(1:27))
df2 <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 2, 3), "value_a1" = c(21, 33, 16), "value_a2" = c(69, 75, 60))
```

This is df1

```
   id value_a value_b value_c value_d
1   1       0     100       0       1
2   1      10     101      -1       2
3   1      21     100      -2       3
4   1      30      95      -2       4
5   1      43      90      -2       5
6   1      53     104      -2       6
7   1      69      88      -1       7
8   1      81      84      -1       8
9   1      93      75       0       9
10  2       5     110       0      10
11  2      16     105       0      11
12  2      27     106       0      12
13  2      33     104       1      13
14  2      45      95       1      14
15  2      61     109       2      15
16  2      75      96       2      16
17  2      90      89       1      17
18  3       2     104      -1      18
19  3      11     104       0      19
20  3      16     104       0      20
21  3      24     103       1      21
22  3      31     106       1      22
23  3      40     103       2      23
24  3      47     101       2      24
25  3      60      99       1      25
26  3      75      98       1      26
27  3      88      97       0      27
```

This is df2

```
  id value_a1 value_a2
1  1       21       69
2  2       33       75
3  3       16       60
```

My result would be df3, which would look like this

```
  id value_a value_c
1  1      53      -2
2  2      61       2
3  3      31       1
```

I wrote this code to show my line of thinking.

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(value_a >= df2$value_a1 & value_a <= df2$value_a2) %>%
  filter(value_a == max(value_a)) %>%
  pull(value_b)
```

This however generates a value with three entry's:

```
[1] 88 95 99
```

These are not the maximum value_b's...

Perhaps `by()` would work, but this gets stuck on using a function on two different df's.

It feels like I'm almost there, but still far away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I hope this helps.

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2) %>% mutate(val=ifelse(value_a>value_a1 & value_a<value_a2,value_b,NA)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% summarise(val=max(val,na.rm=T))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id   val
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   104
2     2   109
3     3   106
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Since I further explained the question, that I wanted to find ```value_a``` and ```value_c```, I used ```slice(which.max())``` and ```select()``` in the last part of your pipe. This works like I want! This is my code:
```
df3 <- df1 %>% left_join(df2) %>% 
  mutate(val=ifelse(value_a>value_a1 & value_a<value_a2,value_b,NA)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(which.max(val))%>%
  select(id, value_a, value_c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try a merge?
Then with data.table syntax:

```
library(data.table)
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)

max_values <- df3[value_a > value_a1 & value_a < value_a2, max(value_b), by = "id"]

max_values
# id  V1
# 1:  1 104
# 2:  2 109
# 3:  3 106
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using data.table package since is just what I'm used to

```
library(data.table)

dt.1 <- data.table("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), "value_a" = c(0, 10, 21, 30, 43, 53, 69, 81, 93, 5, 16, 27, 33, 45, 61, 75, 90, 2, 11, 16, 24, 31, 40, 47, 60, 75, 88), "value_b" = c(100, 101, 100, 95, 90, 104, 88, 84, 75, 110, 105, 106, 104, 95, 109, 96, 89, 104, 104, 104, 103, 106, 103, 101, 99, 98, 97), "value_c" = c(0, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0), "value_d" = c(1:27))
dt.2 <- data.table("id" = c(1, 2, 3), "value_a1" = c(21, 33, 16), "value_a2" = c(69, 75, 60))

dt.3 <- dt.1[id %in% dt.2[,id],max(value_b), by="id"]
setnames(dt.3, "V1", "max_value_b")
dt.3
```

To get corresponding line where b is the max values there are several ways, here's one where I only modified a line from the previous code

```
dt.1[id %in% dt.2[,id],.SD[which.max(value_b), .(value_a, value_b, value_c, value_d)], by="id"]
```

`.SD` means the sub-table you already selected with `by` so for each id selects the local max b and then returns a table `which.max()` selects the row, and finally `.()`  is an alias for list, so lists the columns you wish from that table.

Perhaps a more readable approach is to first select the desired rows

```
max.b.rows <- dt.1[id %in% dt.2[,id], which.max(value_b), by="id"][,V1]
dt.3 <- dt.1[max.b.rows,]
```

BTW, the `id %in% dt.2[,id]` part is just there to make sure you only select maxima for those ids in table 2

Best

Comment: Thanks! I would believe this works best, since both ```left_join``` and ```merge``` unnecessarily enlarge my already big df1 and slow the process down. However, I did not explain the question correctly (and editted it).I am indeed selecting on ```max(value_b)```, but I would like to have ```value_a``` and ```value_c``` of the line containing ```max(value_b)``` in dt.3.  After an ```left_join``` or ```merge``` I would use ```select()``` for this, but how to do this in your example?

Comment: I'll edit my answer in short, sounds straightforward